# How to make an anchor tag not go to a URL/Open a file

Tags: php, html, anchor

I basically have a webpage with two frames.

```
-Left for nav
-Right for main content. I have a text-box here called "file_path"
```

Currently, I have a list of files on the left hand side that I am displaying as anchors. I want the functionality that if the user clicks a file on the left hand frame, I can grab the value and put it in the text-box on the right hand frame. I able to do this successfully, but the problem is that after getting the value in the right frame, my left-frame opens the file in that section ... I want to prevent the file from being open. I only want it to pass the value there.

```
echo "<li><a href=\".$filepath.\" onClick=\"parent.right.document.getElementById('file_path').value='$filepath'\">$filepath</a></li>";
```

I tried merely putting the onClick for the list item, but this way I loose functionality, so that the user feels that the link is clickable. It just appears as static text ... I'd rather have the cursor change when the user goes on it like an anchor tag, but just not open the file ... Is this possible?

```
echo "<li onClick=\"parent.right.document.getElementById('file_path').value='$filepath'\">$filepath</li>";
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just put `<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="...">bla bla bla</a>`

Comment: `a` without `href` is nonstandard. For example, the `a:hover` style won't work in IE.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="nothing.html" onclick="return false;">Clicking me does nothing</a>
```

Returning `false` from the onclick - whether it is from a function's return value or put straight in there - will disable the default behaviour of the anchor.

Comment: Greg, this is interesting, and I wasn't aware .. thanks! However Pate's solution is best suited for me, since I do want to use the onClick function rather than invoking another one that returns false ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the href attribute of the links to be href = 'javascript:void(0);'. They'll be links, but won't go anywhere.

G

Comment: Alternatively, go with your current solution, but use the following css rule: li.someClassForTheseListItems { cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline; }

Comment: ...although it's always best to use links as links: accessibility implications.

Comment: Thanks dartacus ... however, I'm not sure what you mean by accessibility implications. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Apologies - haven't looked back at this for a while. Screen readers, when enumerating links for users, will often just check for links, not any clickable item. So if you want your page to be optimally accessible clickable things should really be links. Times may have changed, so I'd verify this, but AFAIK it's still good practice.